# How do i work around Slash in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my extension i want to get `href` property of `a` object, which is `/photo123456789_987654321`.

But instead i get  `chrome-extension://extension-id/photo123456789_987654321`.

How do i work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing the extension id with a regexp:

```
href_string.replace(/^chrome-extension:\/\/.*?\//, "/");
```

E.g.

```
var href_string = "chrome-extension://extension-id/photo123456789_987654321";
href_string.replace(/^chrome-extension:\/\/.*?\//, "/");

// "/photo123456789_987654321"
```

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: It means 'any character' so `.*?` means: one or more of any character, but not too many (`.*` would result in `extension-id/a/b` being replaced with `/b`).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a more-complicated regex you can just use the first part of the string:

http://jsfiddle.net/3qRQT/

```
var someString = "chrome-extension://extension-id/photo123456789_987654321";

someString.replace("chrome-extension://extension-id","");
```